# Add two select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure why the following does not work?

```
(SELECT MIN(ID) FROM dbo.TABLE_1  WHERE Scenario LIKE '%Full%') + 
(select count(*) from  dbo.TABLE_2  WHERE Scenario LIKE '%Full%')
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Independently of each other they produce the desired output. The first one I get 110 and the second outcome is 8. So I would like the output to show me 118.

Comment: You just need another `SELECT` at the beginning

Comment: duh..that was stupid. Thanks Cory!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a `select` in front:

```
select (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM dbo.TABLE_1  WHERE Scenario LIKE '%Full%') + 
       (select count(*) from  dbo.TABLE_2  WHERE Scenario LIKE '%Full%')
```

Executable statements start with a handful of keywords (such as `select`).  An expression that starts with a `(` is assumed to be a subquery.  Only set-operators such as `union` would be acceptable after the subquery.

Answer (score 4):

add `select` in the front.

```
SELECT (SELECT CAST(MIN(ID) AS INT) FROM dbo.TABLE_1  WHERE Scenario LIKE '%Full%') + 
(select count(*) from  dbo.TABLE_2  WHERE Scenario LIKE '%Full%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(MIN(t1.ID) AS INT),count(t2.*) FROM dbo.TABLE_1 t1,dbo.TABLE_2 t2 WHERE t1.Scenario LIKE '%Full%' and t2.Scenario LIKE '%Full%'
```